# Creating a dynamic table using php based on users input data

Tags: php

Currently I am trying to create a daily class routine using PHP. Firstly the site will have seven days name as check box and a text box where users could enter number of class period.

When user will submit the form the code will create another form inside another table (looks like [this](http://s10.postimg.org/5voakdu89/stack_php.jpg)). And finally user could enter class name, teacher name and the code will store it in database.

**But my problem is creating the table dynamically. I can not finding out how to solve this problem.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Below you can see what I have tried so far:

```
<h1>Form two</h1>

<form action="routine_create_process.php" method="POST">
<h3>How many class period do you want to add?</h3>

<input type="text" name="period"/>

<h3>Avalible class day</h3>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="f[]" value="sat" /> Saturday </label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f[]" value="sun"  /> Sunday </label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f[]"  value="mon" /> Monday </label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f[]"  value="tues" /> Tuesday </label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f[]"  value="thurs" /> Wednesday </label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f[]"  value="thus" /> Thursday </label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f[]"  value="fri" /> Friday </label>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$period=$_POST['period'];
$arr2=$_POST['f'];
?>

<table border='2'>
<?php 
$count=count($arr2)-1;
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
  echo "<tr><td>";
  if($i==0){
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<div class='wrap_p'>";
    for($r=1;$r<=$period;$r++){
      echo "<td>";
      echo "<div class='add_css'>";
      echo $r;
      echo "</div></td>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</table>";
  }
  echo "</tr><tr><td>"; 
  echo $arr2[$i];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type='text' size='20' /></tr></td>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: The variable `$period` is not defined. Can you please update your code.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
<?php

$arr2=$_POST['f'];
$period = $_POST['period'];

?>

<table border='2'>
<?php 
$count=count($arr2)-1;
?>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
<?php
                for($r=1;$r<=$period;$r++){
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<div class='add_css'>";
                    echo $r ;
                    echo "</div></td>";

                }
    for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){

echo "<tr><td>"; 

echo $arr2[$i];

        for($r=1;$r<=$period;$r++)
        {
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<div class='add_css'>";
            echo "<input type='text' size='20' />" ;
            echo "</div></td>";
        }

echo "</td>";


}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: it works , but I also need to display the class period number at the top of the table .

Comment: the number as whole? Just print the $period it will show the number of period.

Comment: I can not understand where should I print the variable which prints period number. I have tried this.

echo "<td>";
            echo "<div class='add_css'>";
            echo $r;
            echo "<input type='text' size='20' />" ;
            echo "</div></td>";

and it returns like this 

http://s8.postimg.org/ckzufr5xx/stack_php2.jpg

but I dont want that

Answer (score 2):

I think this is close to what you need.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$period = 8;
$arr2=array('sat','sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri');
?>
<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th>Days</th>
<?php 
for($i=1;$i <= $period; $i++){
    ?><th><?php echo $i; ?></th><?php
}
?>
</tr>
<?php 
foreach($arr2 as $day){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $day; ?></th>
        <?php
        for($i=1;$i <= $period; $i++){
            ?>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="subject">
                <input type="text" placeholder="subject code">
                <input type="text" placeholder="teachers name">
            </td>
            <?php
        } 
        ?>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem. you get the idea right? remember to replace `$arr2` with your POST input