# How to create a table whose contents dynamically?

Tags: php, html, css

If the user input :

```
$sgl = 2;
$dbl = 0;
$twn = 1;
$trp = 0;
$quad = 0;

$price_room = 250000;
```

I want the result looks like the picture below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQYqr.jpg

I try the code like this :

```
<?php
    $sgl = 2;
    $dbl = 0;
    $twn = 1;
    $trp = 0;
    $quad = 0;

    $price_room = 250000;

    $counter = 0;
    if($sgl>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Single';
        $price = $price_room * 1;
    }

    if($dbl>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Double';
        $price = $price_room * 2;
    }

    if($twn>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Twin';
        $price = $price_room * 2;
    }

    if($trp>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Triple';
        $price = $price_room * 3;
    }

    if($quad>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Quad';
        $price = $price_room * 4;
    }


    // echo $counter;

?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Room type</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $no=1;
    for($i=0;$i<$counter;$i++){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $room_type; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $price; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
        $no++;
    }
?>
    <tr>

        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $price; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it is not working. Output results different from the results output in the picture

How to fix my code so the results as output results in images?

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Lots of problems - `$room_type` will be the same in each loop, as will `$price`. You need to think about having the user input data in an array so you can do a `foreach` and output the data

Comment: You may take a good look on this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809991/creating-a-dynamic-table-using-php-based-on-users-input-data). Hope this helps.

Comment: @J.Titus, Not. Not the problem. I've replaced the picture above

Comment: @samueltoh the rooms will get stored to room array and at last we will print it based on availability of the room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, just use an array to hold those together. First build yourself an array of rates:

```
$rates = array(
    'sgl' => array('rate' => 1, 'type' => 'Single',),
    'dbl' => array('rate' => 2, 'type' => 'Double',),
    'twn' => array('rate' => 2, 'type' => 'Twin',),
    'trp' => array('rate' => 3, 'type' => 'Triple',),
    'quad' => array('rate' => 4, 'type' => 'Quad',),
);
```

Sort of like a table wherein you have the price, labeling and stuff.

Then after that, build an array of your input so that you can apply that into your array of rates and use that key to make your calculations.

Example:

```
// input
$input = array('sgl' => $sgl, 'dbl' => $dbl, 'twn' => $twn, 'trp' => $trp, 'quad' => $quad);
// lay them all out as an array
```

Now you can just match the keys:

```
<?php

$sgl = 2;
$dbl = 0;
$twn = 1;
$trp = 0;
$quad = 0;

// input
$input = array('sgl' => $sgl, 'dbl' => $dbl, 'twn' => $twn, 'trp' => $trp, 'quad' => $quad);

$price_room = 250000;

$rates = array(
    'sgl' => array('rate' => 1, 'type' => 'Single',),
    'dbl' => array('rate' => 2, 'type' => 'Double',),
    'twn' => array('rate' => 2, 'type' => 'Twin',),
    'trp' => array('rate' => 3, 'type' => 'Triple',),
    'quad' => array('rate' => 4, 'type' => 'Quad',),
);

$total = 0;
foreach($input as $key => $user_input) {
    if($user_input > 0) {
        // all of the data are pushed in here
        $result[] = array(
            'no' => $user_input,
            'room_type' => $rates[$key]['type'],
            'price' => $rates[$key]['rate'] * $price_room,
        );

        $total += $rates[$key]['rate'] * $price_room;
    }
}

?>
```

As for presentation, a normal html markup and a `foreach` should do just fine:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<thead><tr><th>No</th><th>Room Type</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>
<?php foreach($result as $r): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['room_type']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['price']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="right"><?php echo $total; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I've tried your code. But the result is different from the output on my pictures. You try to compare the results of your code with the results of my pictures. It is different

Comment: @samueltoh it look different the example you have has 1 single 2 twin, in this answer it has 2 single 1 twin, only the user inputs are different

Comment: ,I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269200/how-to-display-json-object-to-html?noredirect=1#comment62064748_37269200

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code, it will give you output the way you expect.

```
    <?php
    $sgl = 2;
    $dbl = 0;
    $twn = 1;
    $trp = 0;
    $quad = 0;

    $price_room = 250000;

    $rooms = array();

    $counter = 0;
    if($sgl>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Single';
        $price = $price_room * 1;
        $rooms[$room_type] = $price;
    }

    if($dbl>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Double';
        $price = $price_room * 2;
        $rooms[$room_type] = $price;
    }

    if($twn>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Twin';
        $price = $price_room * 2;
        $rooms[$room_type] = $price;
    }

    if($trp>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Triple';
        $price = $price_room * 3;
        $rooms[$room_type] = $price;
    }

    if($quad>0){
        $counter++;
        $room_type = 'Quad';
        $price = $price_room * 4;
        $rooms[$room_type] = $price;
    }


    // echo $counter;

?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Room type</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $no=1;$total_price =0;
    foreach($rooms as $toom_type=>$room_price){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $toom_type; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $room_price; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
        $total_price += $room_price;
        $no++;
    }
?>
    <tr>

        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $total_price ; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

please let me know if any other help needed.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Total = 50000. It is still wrong. Should total = 75000

Comment: @samueltoh i have modified the code it should serve your purpose now. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compact` to add the variables to an array (although you may be able to do this another way).

The loop through them, and use a `switch` to set the values and output.

```
$sgl = 2;
$dbl = 0;
$twn = 1;
$trp = 0;
$quad = 0;
$price_room = 25000;

// compact the variables into an array
$rooms = compact('sgl', 'dbl', 'twn', 'trp', 'quad');

echo '<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Room type</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>';
// set start values
$no = 1;
$total = 0;
// loop through array
foreach ($rooms as $type => $rm)
{
    // only output if greater than 0
    if ($rm > 0)
    {
        // set the values based on the type
        switch ($type) {
            case 'sgl':
                $room_type = 'Single';
                $price = $price_room * 1;
                break;
            case 'dbl':
                $room_type = 'Double';
                $price = $price_room * 2;
                break;
            case 'twn':
                $room_type = 'Twin';
                $price = $price_room * 2;
                break;
            case 'trp':
                $room_type = 'Triple';
                $price = $price_room * 3;
                break;
            case 'quad':
                $room_type = 'Quad';
                $price = $price_room * 4;
                break;
        }
        // output the row
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$no.'</td>
            <td>'.$room_type.'</td>
            <td>'.($rm * $price).'</td>
        </tr>';
        // add to total
        $total += $rm * $price;
        // increment number
        $no++;
    }
}
// output the total and close the table
echo '<tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;">'.$total.'</td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269200/how-to-display-json-object-to-html?noredirect=1#comment62064748_37269200